# Jquery to find replace text on json feed

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I have the following json feed which I loop through as below to apply some css styles:

```
        import({
           "Results":{
              "cars":[
                 {
                    "__":1010,
                    "_":"<div class=\"clearfix\"><img class=\"feed\" src=\"http://example.com/toyota.jpg\"/>
                            <p>Some text....</p>
                            <p><strong>$1000</strong></p>
                        </div>"
                 },
                 {
                    "__":2020,
                    "_":"<div class=\"clearfix\"><img class=\"feed\" src=\"http://example.com/nissan.jpg\"/>
                             <p>Some other text... </p>
                             <p><strong>$2000</strong></p>
                        </div>"
                 },

              ]
           }
        });


         for (var i = 0; i < data.Results["cars"].length; i++) {
              $("#results").append("<p >" + data.Results["cars"][i]["_"] + "</p>");

              $(".clearfix").css({float: "left"; width: "120px"; text-align:"center"; padding: "10px 0"});
         }
```

How can I loop through each element and use jquery to extract the image name (excluding extension) and replace the text of the first `p` tag with it as 
follows and replace the second `p` tag with a radio button that has the same value as the image name.

```
        <div class="clearfix" style="float:left;width:120px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0">
           <img src="http://example.com/toyota.jpg" >
           <p>Toyota</p>
           <p><input type="radio" value="Toyota" name="cartype"> </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Iterating for every element in cars array
[].forEach.call(data.Results.cars, function(inst){

    // Fetching the value of key _
    var _html = inst["_"];

    // Fetching the src of image by making string a jquery object
    var _src = $(_html).find("img").attr("src");

    // Building html
    var _h = '<div class="clearfix" style="float:left;width:120px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0">'
                +'<img src="'+_src+'" >'
                +'<p>'+_scr.split(".")[0]+'</p>'
                +'<p><input type="radio" value="'+_scr.split(".")[0]+'" name="cartype"> </p>'
             +'</div>';

    // Appending html to #results
    $("#results").append(_h);

});
```

Comment: void: `_scr.split(".")[0]` will give `http://example.com/toyota` instead of `toyota` won't it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit the previous code but I didn't apply. So I'm posting this answer.
I think it will work for you.

```
[].forEach.call(data.Results.cars, function(inst){

    // Fetching the value of key _
    var _html = inst["_"];

    // Fetching the src of image by making string a jquery object
    var _src = $(_html).find("img").attr("src");

    //Extracting the image's name
    var _imagesName = _scr.split("/")[_scr.split("/").length-1].split(".")[0];
    // Building html
    var _h = '<div class="clearfix" style="float:left;width:120px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0">'
                +'<img src="'+_src+'" >'
                +'<p>'+_imagesName+'</p>'
                +'<p><input type="radio" value="'+imagesName'" name="cartype"> </p>'
             +'</div>';

    // Appending html to #results
    $("#results").append(_h);

});
```

Comment: The [].forEach.call doesn't work in IE8 since it doesn't support array.prototype.foreach?